# How do I get `ls -l` output for a link recursively until reached the original file?

Tags: shell-script, ls, symlink

Let me give an example (it's just an example taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/484561/256099)):

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Mar 16  2015 /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor -> /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Mar 16  2015 /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor -> /usr/bin/gedit
$ ls -l /usr/bin/gedit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 588064 Mar 27  2014 /usr/bin/gedit
```

Here you can see that I've to use `ls -l` three times for reaching to destination. (3<sup>rd</sup> time is for making sure that `/usr/bin/gedit` is not a link`)

Is there any way (by means of making script or another command etc.) that I can get expected output like:

```
$ <improved ls -l> /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Mar 16  2015 /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor -> /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Mar 16  2015 /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor -> /usr/bin/gedit
```

Another good output may be:

```
$ <some-command> /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor
/usr/bin/gnome-text-editor > /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor > /usr/bin/gedit
```

Comment: Also be aware, that links can be circular: a -> b b -> a

Answer (score 13):

In this case, that's a Debian "alternative", so to get more details, you could use:

```
$ update-alternatives --display gnome-text-editor
gnome-text-editor - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/gedit
  link currently points to /usr/bin/gedit
  link gnome-text-editor is /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor
  slave gnome-text-editor.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/gnome-text-editor.1.gz
/usr/bin/gedit - priority 50
  slave gnome-text-editor.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/gedit.1.gz
/usr/bin/leafpad - priority 40
  slave gnome-text-editor.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/leafpad.1.gz
```

More generally, on Linux, you can use the `namei` command to know about all the symlinks involved in the resolution of a path (also mount points with `-x`):

```
$ namei -lx /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor
f: /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor
Drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root usr
drwxr-xr-x root root bin
lrwxrwxrwx root root gnome-text-editor -> /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor
Drwxr-xr-x root root   /
drwxr-xr-x root root   etc
drwxr-xr-x root root   alternatives
lrwxrwxrwx root root   gnome-text-editor -> /usr/bin/gedit
Drwxr-xr-x root root     /
drwxr-xr-x root root     usr
drwxr-xr-x root root     bin
-rwxr-xr-x root root     gedit
```

For a more direct answer to your question, I'd do something like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat || exit
ret=0
for file do
  n=0
  while
    ls -ld -- "$file" || ! ret=1 && [ -L "$file" ]
  do
    if ((++n > 40)) && [ ! -e "$file" ]; then
      echo >&2 too many symlinks
      ret=1
      break
    fi
    zstat -A target +link -- "$file" || ! ret=1 || break
    case $target in
      (/*) file=$target;;
      (*)  file=$file:h/$target
    esac
  done
done
exit "$ret"
```

That may not give you all the information you need to understand what's going on. Compare for instance:

```
$ ./resolve-symlink b/b/b/b/x/b
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane 1 Mar 18 15:37 b/b/b/b/x/b -> a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane 4 Mar 18 15:37 b/b/b/b/x/a -> ../a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane 26 Mar 18 15:15 b/b/b/b/x/../a -> /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Nov  5  2013 /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor -> /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Mar 15 12:21 /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor -> /usr/bin/gedit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10344 Nov 12 17:18 /usr/bin/gedit
```

With:

```
$ namei -lx b/b/b/b/x/b
f: b/b/b/b/x/b
lrwxrwxrwx stephane stephane b -> .
drwxr-xr-x stephane stephane   .
lrwxrwxrwx stephane stephane b -> .
drwxr-xr-x stephane stephane   .
lrwxrwxrwx stephane stephane b -> .
drwxr-xr-x stephane stephane   .
lrwxrwxrwx stephane stephane b -> .
drwxr-xr-x stephane stephane   .
lrwxrwxrwx stephane stephane x -> 2
drwxr-xr-x stephane stephane   2
lrwxrwxrwx stephane stephane b -> a
lrwxrwxrwx stephane stephane   a -> ../a
drwxr-xr-x stephane stephane     ..
lrwxrwxrwx stephane stephane     a -> /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor
Drwxr-xr-x root     root           /
drwxr-xr-x root     root           usr
drwxr-xr-x root     root           bin
lrwxrwxrwx root     root           gnome-text-editor -> /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor
Drwxr-xr-x root     root             /
drwxr-xr-x root     root             etc
drwxr-xr-x root     root             alternatives
lrwxrwxrwx root     root             gnome-text-editor -> /usr/bin/gedit
Drwxr-xr-x root     root               /
drwxr-xr-x root     root               usr
drwxr-xr-x root     root               bin
-rwxr-xr-x root     root               gedit
```

Answer (score 10):

`readlink` is the command you are looking for.

```
$ readlink -e /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor
/usr/bin/gedit
```

Various flags (`-f`, `-e`, `-m`) are available according to how you'd like to behave in case of broken links - see `man readlink` for details.

Comment: Thanks; but it doesn't give the information about intermediate file(s) (like `/etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor`) which may be useful

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following script:

```
$ cat myll
#!/bin/bash
name="$1"
while [[ -L "$name" ]]; do
ls -l "$name"; 
name=`readlink "$name"`;
done
```

Example output:

```
$ myll /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Mar 16  2015 /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor -> /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Mar 16  2015 /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor -> /usr/bin/gedit
```

Here `[[ -L "$name" ]]` checks whether file is link or not and `readlink "$name"` reads link and save it to variable `name` for next loop. And hence `while [[ -L "$name" ]]` loops until original target/file reached.

---

For second work-around, you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash
name="$1"
while [[ -L "$name" ]]; do
echo -n "$name > ";
name=`readlink "$name"`;
done
echo "$name"
```

Example output:

```
$ myls /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor
/usr/bin/gnome-text-editor > /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor > /usr/bin/gedit
```

Comment: That won't work properly for relative symlinks (as relative symlinks are relative to the symlink's host directory, not to your current working directory).